# Can I use ORM (EF or nHibernate) in Client side application without hampering performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nhibernate, c#-4.0, orm

I am working on WPF client applcation. I never seen anybody using ORM in client side.

I am putting here some analysis of using ORM in client vs server application.

1. By default it is Lazy. This means, till the query executes first time nothing happens but after that query is cached. Now this can be understood in server apps, but clientside is started frequently so can I use eager loading in client application?
2. If dll is tampered, will it be easy for the hacker to find the data as he can see all database structure right away?
3. Any other implications while using ORM in client side?

Thanks,
Omkar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) both EF and nhibernate can be set to eager
2) nto tampered with dll, but both have pipline type designs so code could be inserted into pipline - for instance EF/Nhibernate profilers do this
3) Client side should not be so different - we have used EF, server / client and found no differences

Comment: Thanks. Any advantages in using ORM in client side?

Comment: Speed of development mainly, no runtime errors to misspelling column names, strong type casting and intelisense.  Client side validation of datatypes and constraints.  If you have learnt LINQ it rocks and you can use this (LINQ to SQL is no longer recommeneded - but LINQ to EF/Nhibernate is cool)

Comment: O and they protect against sql injection attacks which can happen with client application if you concatinate strings with Ui elements instead of parametised querries - not saying you do just an observation :-)

Comment: no problems - if you get no better answers, then accept my post as an answer because i'm chasing points - competition in the office :-)

Comment: If you choose to use EF, then starting with EF 4.1 there is a pretty nice data binding story for WPF. The DbSet.Local property returns an ObservableCollection which interacts very nicely with WPF data binding. See this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/08/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-model-with-master-detail-wpf-application.aspx

Answer (score 2):

We are using it for our rich client application and are having not many problems with it. You have to change your thinking a bit - but we really liked the model classes (instead of using hand-crafted sql).

- I would really overthink your opinion regarding eager loading. I would try to develop the application with lazy loading and if you have problems with it, try to change to eager loading. Making "view data objects" and mapping the db entities to this may help with lazy loading problems (Ayende Rahien wrote a lot over these things - you may check his blog: http://ayende.com/blog - a good starter may be his MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx)
- tampered DLLs - I don't really have an opinion to this point
- other implications - you have to think about session management as it is not so easy as with server side applications - this was the biggest change for us. But on the other hand you get freed of "there is already a data reader associated with this connection" problems.

The whole session management can be overwhelming at the start, so I think you shoud start with  a good structure - like the one shown in Ayende's article. I you don't like this approach, you can try a "thin" ORM like Dapper: http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/